# Terminology for the referent of a foreign key

Tags: sql

I think my mind is blanking, but what is the correct terminology for the referent of a foreign key relation?   Is there a succinct term for this?

i.e., WidgetTypes table contains XYZ and is the *XXX* of the Widget table's type_id column..

Comment: Don't know an answer, but while we are being pedantic, I find it strange that a table would "do" something other than store data or represent entities.

Comment: I have heard the Master / Child relationship to describe the two, but can't remember hearing anything very exact. I'm interested in seeing if someone has some terms we can adopt. :)

Comment: @meriton - :).  Is the edit better?

Comment: Referent or FK Reference should be fine, I think.

Comment: @Conrad and @JNK - nothing wrong with it, just curious if there's some term (probably squirreled away in some academic journal) for this specificly.

Comment: Actually, reference is ambiguous whereas referent is precise -- the thing referred to. P.S. If you're not sure your mind is blanking, it is blanking.

Comment: If the A is the referant of B, then B is the <what> of A?

Comment: @Tim - or it could mean the term doesn't exist.  Referent isn't very precise either.   I found something that's warmer http://books.google.com/books?id=K_CXWSrXyWoC&pg=PA414&lpg=PA414&dq=foreign+key+%2Breferent&source=bl&ots=-nssMXqbWO&sig=FoWYO4321mQPXqxPMdDw6O7kFWo&hl=en&ei=Dt-UTaKZKqXSiALTttHuCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=foreign%20key%20%2Breferent&f=false  Of course, I've never heard anyone say 'Indirect property'

Comment: You could use `is the referenced table`, I like the referenced/referencing terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest:

WidgetTypes table contains XYZ and *is referenced by* the Widget table's type_id column.

or perhaps better

WidgetTypes table contains XYZ and *is referred to by* the Widget table's type_id column.

because simple plain english is more understandable than terms the reader has to look up in a dictionary.

I would reserve Parent/Child for hierarchical data. It feels weird to be my parent's parent ...

**Edit**: While Tim is correct in pointing out that the noun "reference" is ambiguous with respect to direction, I have never perceived such ambiguity with the verb "to reference" used by my suggestion. Be that as it may, the direction of "refer to", which my second suggestion relies on, is clear.

Comment: +1 And please don't be so hyperbolically obtuse in your circumlocutions.

Comment: Simplicity and clarity may sometimes require the technical term to avoid ambiguity.  You can "refer to" something or "make a reference" to something, and the thing you are referring to can be called "the reference", so "reference" is ambiguous with respect to the direction. Whereas 'referent' means simply and plainly 'that which is being referred to'.  A foreign key constraint enforces the rule that a value (or combination of values) in a table must refer to a unique value (or unique combination of values) in another table (or in the same table). The referent of a foreign key is a unique key.

Answer (score 0):

The WidgetTypes table contains the types of widgets and is related to Widgets through the Widget table's type_id column.

Parent/Child or Primary/Foreign work.